# For how many distinct triangles ABC, with AB = $2011$, are both $\cos(2\angle{A} + 3\angle{C})$ and $\sin(2\angle{B} + \angle{C})$ integers?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I came across a tough geometry question:

> For how many distinct triangles $\text{ABC}$, with $\text{AB}$ = $2011$, are both $\cos(2\angle{A} + 3\angle{C})$ and $\sin(2\angle{B} + \angle{C})$  integers?

**My attempt:**

For $\cos(2\angle{A} + 3\angle{C})$ and $\sin(2\angle{B} + \angle{C})$ to be integers, then $$2\angle{A} + 3\angle{C} = 90, 180, 270, 360, ...$$
$$2\angle{B} + \angle{C} = 90, 180, 270, 360, ...$$
and we know that $$\angle{A} + \angle{B} + \angle{C} = 180$$
That creates 3 equations for 3 unknowns, but is there a simpler way to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\cos(2A+3C) \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow 2A+3B = \dfrac{n\pi}{2}$,

and $\sin(2B+C) \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow 2B+C = \dfrac{k\pi}{2}$, and

$A+B+C = \pi$. Solve for $A,B,C$.

**For example**, $B = \dfrac{\pi(2k+n-4)}{10}$. Then you solve $ 0 < B < \pi \Rightarrow 0 < 2k+n-4 < 10$. Can you finish it? Notice you have two others for $A,C$ as well.

Comment: I solved for B and got $B = \pi/10*(2k+n-4)$. What do I do with that now? How do I check what values of k and n work?

Comment: I got for B: $4 < 2k + n < 14$, A: $6 < n - 2k < 16$, C: $-4 < 3k - n < 6$. First of all are those right?

Comment: There are the solutions according to wolfram: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x%2C+y%2C+and+z%3A+2x%2B3y+%3D+n*pi%2F2%2C+2y+%2Bz+%3D+k*pi%2F2%2C+x%2By%2Bz+%3D+pi) How exactly to I solve the inequalities to get the solutions that wolfram gets: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-6+%3C+n-3k+%3C+4%2C+4+%3C2k%2Bn+%3C14%2C++-8%3Ck-2n+%3C+2)